# Canvas editing mode in Umbraco 5. Where is it?

Tags: umbraco

Is there a web-side editing mode (Canvas editor) that comes with v5 like there was with v4.x?

I have searched around and only found one mention to it in a past post on someones blog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canvas editing isn't in v5 yet as far as I'm aware. As it was a ground up rewrite of the entire code base, the core team have concentrated on core functionality first (the features that are used by most users of the system).

5.0 has most of the core functionality, but it is missing a few of the features that are in v4. For example, while the Membership code is there in the core, there is no Members section to manage the members yet (that's coming March 2012). There's also no timed publish/unpublish, amongst other things.

The current plan is to release lots of small updates fairly regularly that add in the missing functionality, as well as new features. You can see what's coming up in the next releases on the progress track site here: http://progress.umbraco.org/

There's no mention of Canvas mode yet, but you can always raise it as an issue on the Issue Tracker for v5 http://issues.umbraco.org/ and one of the core team should get back to you about when it will make it into the core!